# Ghidra disassembly: x86 MOV instruction with colon

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, ghidra

I came across an unfamilar syntax when studying a dissassembly with Ghidra.

One line contains

```
MOV EAX,GS:[0x14]
```

what does the colon syntax mean?

I'm actually fairly new to all of this, both ASM and Ghidra analysis. I understand that this instruction moves "something from somewhere" into the 32 bit register EAX, but I don't understand how to interpret either the `GS` or the colon symbols.

Comment: Strong chance this is a thread local read - gs is a segment register:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234817/what-does-this-instruction-do-mov-gs0x14-eax

Answer (score 0):

The colon means that this is a [segment override](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#CS.2C_SS.2C_DS.2C_ES.2C_FS_and_GS_segment_override_prefixes), if you don't use the default segment register.